# Get Members In Shared Mailboxes office 365

Tags: office365

Hi every one i have a problem to get access list members In Shared Mailboxes office 365 using Unified API.

i'm using this endpoint API https://graph.microsoft.com

I hope anyone can help me

Comment: I answered your question.  Can you please elaborate more on why you need shared mailbox membership?  We may be able to provide you an alternate way to achieve your scenario.

Comment: Thank's Venkat for your answer. I need shared mailboxes because have a project with it. I'm only need the shared mailboxes member list and that project is finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Office 365 Unified API doesn't yet support access to shared mailbox content or membership.  Access to content is on our roadmap, and something we hope to enable before the end of the year.  We are looking at membership as well, but have no firm plans.

Comment: Thank's Venkat, but now i use powershell to access office365 and can get the shared folder on exchange. I'm using php script to access powershell.