# List Shared Mailboxes in Office 365 via REST and JavaScript

Tags: exchange-server, office365, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

I've been searching with no luck for a way to find/list all shared mailboxes in Exchange Online via webservice. Apparently Office 365 Graph does not support this yet, as posted in this answer on 2016-06-30: [Get Members In Shared Mailboxes office 365](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31020214/get-members-in-shared-mailboxes-office-365?answertab=votes#tab-top)

I know I could be using the EWS Managed API https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj536567(v=exchg.150).aspx to access the mail items inside a shared mailbox, but unfortunately it seems you have to know the shared mailboxes' names before accessing them.

How do I get a list of all the shared mailboxes a user has access to from some JS?

Answer (score 0):

It is easy using the Exchange online cmdlets via PowerShell. You can refer the command below to get the shared mailboxes:

```
$UserCredential = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session
Get-Mailbox | where {$_.recipientTypeDetails -eq 'sharedmailbox' }
```

Comment: I don't have PowerShell available. It shall be done via JavaScript from a (SharePoint) Website.

Comment: Modified my question accordingly.

Comment: The Office 365 REST or Microsoft Graph REST doesn't support to distinguish the shared mail box from normal user at present. You may submit the feedback from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com) if you require this feature.

Comment: As a workaround, you can also build a service to using C# run the PowerShell command above and using the JavaScript call your service. You can refer [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/) about executing PowerShell using C#.

Comment: If you post the workaround as answer, I'll mark it as solution.